# How to set List View as default view in Hybris PCM Backoffice

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I am a bit new to the Hybris platform. I am working with the Backoffice PCM on Hybris 6.7.

I would like to change the default browser display when using the PCM Backoffice. Currently the default behavior renders Grid View but I would like to use List View instead. I will like to either remove entirely the grid view option (or disable it) and automatically open products in list view instead.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to customize the xml to obtain the desired behavior. The best approach is creating a new extension from template ybackoffice to consolidate your changes.

Basically, the original extension have these lines:

```
<context type="Product" component="pcmbackoffice-assortment-collection-browser" >
    <cb:collection-browser xmlns:cb="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/config/collectionbrowser">
        <cb:available-molds default-mold="grid-view">
            <cb:mold spring-bean="listViewCollectionBrowserMoldStrategy"/>
            <cb:mold spring-bean="gridViewCollectionBrowserMoldStrategy"/>
        </cb:available-molds>
    </cb:collection-browser>
</context>
```

Just copy and paste in your new extension in the file <myextension>-backoffice-config.xml and remove the line correspondent to the grid view (for removing the option), eg.:

```
<context type="Product" component="pcmbackoffice-assortment-collection-browser" >
    <cb:collection-browser xmlns:cb="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/config/collectionbrowser">
        <cb:available-molds default-mold="list-view">
            <cb:mold spring-bean="listViewCollectionBrowserMoldStrategy"/>
        </cb:available-molds>
    </cb:collection-browser>
</context>
```

Do ant clean all, and after HAC update in your extension.

Ps.: You can apply these changes through orchestrator to see the result in live, before create the new extension.